# Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.> (line 3485,col 33) Parse error. Found "-", expected "("

Tags: android, android-studio

My Application was working good but when I restarted Android Studio I got this error:
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> (line 3485,col 33) Parse error. Found "-", expected "("
>     Problem stacktrace : 
>       com.github.javaparser.GeneratedJavaParser.generateParseException(GeneratedJavaParser.java:10037)
>       com.github.javaparser.GeneratedJavaParser.jj_consume_token(GeneratedJavaParser.java:9893)
>       com.github.javaparser.GeneratedJavaParser.Parameters(GeneratedJavaParser.java:1329)
>       com.github.javaparser.GeneratedJavaParser.MethodDeclaration(GeneratedJavaParser.java:1253)
>       com.github.javaparser.GeneratedJavaParser.ClassOrInterfaceBodyDeclaration(GeneratedJavaParser.java:1006)
>       com.github.javaparser.GeneratedJavaParser.ClassOrInterfaceBody(GeneratedJavaParser.java:899)
>       com.github.javaparser.GeneratedJavaParser.ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration(GeneratedJavaParser.java:463)
>       com.github.javaparser.GeneratedJavaParser.ClassOrInterfaceBodyDeclaration(GeneratedJavaParser.java:967)
>       com.github.javaparser.GeneratedJavaParser.ClassOrInterfaceBody(GeneratedJavaParser.java:899)
>       com.github.javaparser.GeneratedJavaParser.ClassOrInterfaceDeclaration(GeneratedJavaParser.java:463)
>       com.github.javaparser.GeneratedJavaParser.CompilationUnit(GeneratedJavaParser.java:209)
>       com.github.javaparser.JavaParser.parse(JavaParser.java:123)
>       com.github.javaparser.JavaParser.simplifiedParse(JavaParser.java:323)
>       com.github.javaparser.JavaParser.parse(JavaParser.java:198)
>       butterknife.plugin.FinalRClassBuilder.brewJava(FinalRClassBuilder.java:40)
>       butterknife.plugin.ButterKnifePlugin$applyPlugin$1$1$1.execute(ButterKnifePlugin.kt:34)
>       butterknife.plugin.ButterKnifePlugin$applyPlugin$1$1$1.execute(ButterKnifePlugin.kt:15)
>       org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:632)
>       org.gradle.api.internal.AbstractTask$TaskActionWrapper.execute(AbstractTask.java:615)
>       org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeAction(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:95)
>       org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.executeActions(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:76)
>       org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteActionsTaskExecuter.java:55)
>       org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.execute(SkipUpToDateTaskExecuter.java:62)
>       org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ValidatingTaskExecuter.execute(ValidatingTaskExecuter.java:58)
>       org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.execute(SkipEmptySourceFilesTaskExecuter.java:88)
>       org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.execute(ResolveTaskArtifactStateTaskExecuter.java:46)
>       org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.execute(SkipTaskWithNoActionsExecuter.java:51)
>       org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.execute(SkipOnlyIfTaskExecuter.java:54)
>       org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.execute(ExecuteAtMostOnceTaskExecuter.java:43)
>       org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.execution.CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.execute(CatchExceptionTaskExecuter.java:34)
>       org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:236)
>       org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker$1.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
>       org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
>       org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
>       org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:61)
>       org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:228)
>       org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter$EventFiringTaskWorker.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:215)
>       org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.processTask(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:77)
>       org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.AbstractTaskPlanExecutor$TaskExecutorWorker.run(AbstractTaskPlanExecutor.java:58)
>       org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.process(DefaultTaskPlanExecutor.java:32)
>       org.gradle.execution.taskgraph.DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.execute(DefaultTaskGraphExecuter.java:113)
>       org.gradle.execution.SelectedTaskExecutionAction.execute(SelectedTaskExecutionAction.java:37)
>       org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
>       org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.access$000(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:23)
>       org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter$1.proceed(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:43)
>       org.gradle.execution.DryRunBuildExecutionAction.execute(DryRunBuildExecutionAction.java:32)
>       org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:37)
>       org.gradle.execution.DefaultBuildExecuter.execute(DefaultBuildExecuter.java:30)
>       org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:196)
>       org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher$3.execute(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:193)
>       org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
>       org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
>       org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
>       --> 
>    org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuildStages(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:193)
>       org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.doBuild(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:119)
>       org.gradle.initialization.DefaultGradleLauncher.run(DefaultGradleLauncher.java:102)
>       org.gradle.launcher.exec.GradleBuildController.run(GradleBuildController.java:71)
>       org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.BuildModelActionRunner.run(BuildModelActionRunner.java:50)
>       org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>       org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:43)
>       org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner$1.execute(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
>       org.gradle.internal.Transformers$4.transform(Transformers.java:169)
>       org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:106)
>       org.gradle.internal.progress.DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.run(DefaultBuildOperationExecutor.java:56)
>       org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.run(RunAsBuildOperationBuildActionRunner.java:40)
>       org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.runner.SubscribableBuildActionRunner.run(SubscribableBuildActionRunner.java:75)
>       org.gradle.launcher.exec.ChainingBuildActionRunner.run(ChainingBuildActionRunner.java:35)
>       org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:41)
>       org.gradle.launcher.exec.InProcessBuildActionExecuter.execute(InProcessBuildActionExecuter.java:26)
>       org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:75)
>       org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.execute(ContinuousBuildActionExecuter.java:49)
>       org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:44)
>       org.gradle.tooling.internal.provider.ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.execute(ServicesSetupBuildActionExecuter.java:29)
>       org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ExecuteBuild.doBuild(ExecuteBuild.java:67)
>       org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>       org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>       org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.WatchForDisconnection.execute(WatchForDisconnection.java:47)
>       org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>       org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ResetDeprecationLogger.execute(ResetDeprecationLogger.java:26)
>       org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>       org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.execute(RequestStopIfSingleUsedDaemon.java:34)
>       org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>       org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:74)
>       org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput$2.call(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>       org.gradle.util.Swapper.swap(Swapper.java:38)
>       org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.ForwardClientInput.execute(ForwardClientInput.java:72)
>       org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>       org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogAndCheckHealth.execute(LogAndCheckHealth.java:55)
>       org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>       org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.LogToClient.doBuild(LogToClient.java:60)
>       org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>       org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>       org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.EstablishBuildEnvironment.doBuild(EstablishBuildEnvironment.java:72)
>       org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.BuildCommandOnly.execute(BuildCommandOnly.java:36)
>       org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.api.DaemonCommandExecution.proceed(DaemonCommandExecution.java:120)
>       org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.exec.StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy$1.run(StartBuildOrRespondWithBusy.java:50)
>       org.gradle.launcher.daemon.server.DaemonStateCoordinator$1.run(DaemonStateCoordinator.java:297)
>       org.gradle.internal.concurrent.ExecutorPolicy$CatchAndRecordFailures.onExecute(ExecutorPolicy.java:54)
>       org.gradle.internal.concurrent.StoppableExecutorImpl$1.run(StoppableExecutorImpl.java:40)
>       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
>       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
>       java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had same problem in my project. I found out that I used `-` instead of `_` for an id in my layout xml file. Check for using any `-` in your project. For example replace:

`android:id="@+id/button-one"`

with:

`android:id="@+id/button_one"`